# PHP e AJAX, o que estou fazendo errado?

Tags: php, ajax

Amigos, estou fazendo um AJAX com PHP mas o registro está indo vazio. O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
function newColor() {
    var nome = document.getElementById("descricao_cor").value;
    var cor = document.getElementById("hexadecimal").value;
    alert (nome);
    alert(cor);
    $.ajax({
        url: "atualiza-cor.php",  
        type: "GET",
        data: { descricao_cor: "nome", hexadecimal: "cor" },   
        cache: false,
        success: function() { 
        document.adm.submit();
        $('#btnSelecionar').trigger('click');
    }
});
}
```

Os alerts funcionam direitinho. E aí o PHP está assim:

```
//NOVA COR
if (isset($_GET['novaCor']) && ($_GET['novaCor']) != '') {
    echo $sql_novacor = 'INSERT INTO veiculos0_cores (descricao_cor,relevancia,hexadecimal) VALUES("' . $_POST['nome'] . '","", "' . $_POST['cor'] . '")';
    mysql_query($sql_novacor) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

E um registro é inserido, mas é vazio.
Não estou encontrando o problema. Alguém me ajuda, por favor?

[]´s

Comment: No PHP vc está verificando se $_GET['novaCor'] está setado, mas vc não está mandando. No insert vc está colocando no value $_POST['nome'] e $_POST['cor'] mas o metodo que vc está passando é GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você parece não estar usando o método `POST`. Simplifique usando `$.post`:

```
$.post({
    'url': "atualiza-cor.php",
    'data': {
        'descricao_cor': $("#descricao_cor").val(),
        'hexadecimal': $("#hexadecimal").val()
    },
    'success': function() { 
        document.adm.submit();
        $('#btnSelecionar').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Lembrando: Você estava retornando uma string para `descricao_cor` e `hexadecimal`. Se você tirar as aspas vai retornar o valor que está nas variáveis `descricao_cor` e `hexadecimal`.

Comment: Obrigado Klaider, mas a que esse dado significa->$("#descricao_cor")? Porque continua inserindo vazio...

Comment: É quase o mesmo que `document.getElementById("descricao_cor").value`, mas é função do jQuery (você está usando ele). Use `alert` para ver o que sai.

Comment: Valeu, obrigado mesmo!